# Knockout binding does not update model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I only started to use Knockout but I was already experienced with MVVM as applied in WPF. The issue I am encountering is that the my Knockout view model wrapping the model object does not update that original model. Here is a small example:

HTML

```
<select name="size" id="sel-size" data-bind="options: sizes, value: size"></select>
```

JS

```
// default settings
var settings = {
    size: 5
};

// settings view model
var settingsVM = function () {
    return {
        sizes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        size: ko.observable(settings.size)
    }
}();

// subscribe to changes
settingsVM.size.subscribe(function() {
    alert("Model: " + settings.size + " / VM: " + settingsVM.size());
})

ko.applyBindings(settingsVM);
```

[View in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ucodia/1me87399/)

When the drop-down selection is changed, only `settingsVM.size()` from the view model is updated but `settings.size` from the model remains the same.

It seems that initializing an `observable` with a reference does not keep that reference as a backing field for the property accessor. What am I missing about the MVVM way of Knockout?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value of the select, it is in effect over-writing the contents of your size observable. If you want to set up a backing-field type arrangement, you'll have to use a computed observable with read/write.

Also, if you do want to update the original 'settings' object, you'll need to deal with that rather than the settings.size property alone. Something like this will keep the original model in step with the select:

```
// settings view model
var settingsVM = function () {
  var self=this;
  self.settings = ko.observable({
    size: 5
  });
  self.sizes =   [{size:1},{size:2},{size:3},{size:4},{size:5}];
  self.size = ko.computed({
          read:function(){
            return self.settings();
          },
          write:function(val){
            self.settings(val);
   }});
   self.size.subscribe(function() {

            alert("Model: " + self.settings().size + " / VM: " + self.size().size);
        });
};

ko.applyBindings(new settingsVM());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1me87399/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The dirty little secret of Knockout is that it's not really MVVM. It doesn't have structure for data modeling separate from viewmodeling, so it's just VVM. In an ordinary app design, the data model is on the server, and the "model" in the app is a set of simple AJAX routines for bringing it pieces into the viewmodel. Knockout doesn't concern itself with AJAX, so how you handle that part of your app is up to you (but it's usually pretty simple).

In your question, you expect the model to automatically update to reflect the corresponding viewmodel element. That's redundant; it's not clear that you need something separate that just copies a value from the viewmode. The viewmodel can just subsume the model. But if you have more model-y stuff in mind to do, so that you do need your model elements to be collected together in a structure, Will Jenkins' suggestion of using `subscribe` is the most straightforward way of responding to changes in the viewmodel.

In the comments below, Will Jenkins brings up the utility functions Knockout provides to convert between JSON and observables. These are also helpful for migrating back and forth between a model and a viewmodel.

See also: [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: That would indeed mean that Knockout is not "model aware". Once you pull out a model from a server, edit it through a view model and want to persist it back to the server, that means you have to rewrite your model from scratch? Also having to subscribe to a proxy to update the original reference sounds redundant to me.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use subscribe at all, it's a bit of an anti-pattern with knockout imo. Regarding server round trips, it's easy - you can map straight from json to your vm and then use a utility function such as ko.toJSON to de-knockoutify your vm to post it back. See here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Comment: @Ucodia I think you'll find that Knockout is simpler if you don't insist on following a pattern of having a separate model. Your model is on the server.     You just need to get data into your app and to write data from your app back to the server.

Comment: How is this a "dirty little secret"? The WPF flavour of MVVM isn't "model aware" either unless you specifically add INPC to the model layer, which is a highly-contentious topic for some anyway. In WPF the VM property setters typically propagate changes back down to the model; the KO equivalent of that is the subscriber functions. All he needs to do is either update the model in `settingsVM.size.subscribe` or do it all in one go when it's time to submit. It's not really any different to WPF.

Comment: @RoyJ I am not insisting in following a pattern and that's I ask in what way is Knockout different. Now if I wrap a decomposed model inside a view model, it also means that I have to later rebuild the model from a view model as there is no way to automatically unwrap a decomposed model (you obviously not gonna send back a view model). When you can wrap neatly, you don't need to care about such a thing without any extra step and it is certainly not the responsibility of the view model.

Comment: @MarkFeldman It is possible to make MVVM aware of model updates if you can choose to put your model as a backing field. You get both model updates and UI notification in the same package. I now understand that Knockout does allow such a thing which means you have to update your model from `subscribe` event.

Comment: @WillJenkins mapping is indeed a nice way of initializing your view model but the issue with `ko.toJSON()`is that it only unwraps the view model which often have extra properties (like computed ones), you still have no way to get back a pure model.

Comment: @Ucodia - ko.toJSON and ko.toJS do unwrap computed observables (see https://jsfiddle.net/whgocLnx/).

Comment: @Roy J - ko.mapping is for wrapping JSON from the server in to knockout-aware objects, not unwrapping viewmodels

Comment: @WillJenkins But that is the issue, computed property are really a view model thing, they don't belong on a model, they are usually just a presentation helper. If your model has `firstname` and `lastname` you surely don't want to get back a `fullname` property from the view model. `computed` properties should not be unwrapped!

Comment: Well, the function is called 'ko.toJS', not 'ko.producePureViewModel' so it does what it says on the tin. I think the key word is 'usually' - sometimes you want computed observable values to be unwrapped. And if you don't, it's trivial to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not updating is because your `settings.size` is not an observable and your code does not provide to use `settings.size` as selected size in html.

```
// default Model for settings
function settings(){
    this.size = ko.observable(5);
}

// settings view model
var settingsVM = function () {    
    return {
        sizes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        settings: new settings()
    }
}();

// subscribe to changes
settingsVM.settings.size.subscribe(function() {
    alert("model: " + settingsVM.settings.size());
})

ko.applyBindings(settingsVM);
```

see updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvtrinidad/1me87399/3/)